# Как получить ответ от сервера, когда response массив?

Tags: golang, golang-struct

```
package main

import (
  "github.com/SevereCloud/vksdk/v2/object"
  "github.com/SevereCloud/vksdk/v2/api"
  "log"
)

var response struct {
   Response []object.JSONObject `json:"response"`
}

func main() {
    vk := api.NewVK("")//token
    err := vk.Execute(`return [1, 2, 3];`, &response)
    if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
     }
    log.Print(response.Response)
}
```

Возвращается ошибка: 2021/10/24 13:25:47 json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type struct { Response []object.JSONObject "json:"response"" }
exit status 1

Comment: попробуйте заменить `[]object.JSONObject` на `map[string]interface{}`

Comment: **2021/10/25 16:08:15 json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type struct { Response map[string]interface {} "json:\"response\"" }
exit status 1**

Comment: По ошибке можно предположить, что в json-e нет свойства `response`.